# Submitting a form in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a form that submits values to an api that I have set up with this code

```
export default class login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { email: "test", password: "test" }
  }

  handleButtonPress() {
    console.log("pressed");
    params = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }
    api.login(params)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
        <FormInput onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}/>
        <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
        <FormInput secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}/>
        <Button
          raised
          icon={{name: 'check'}}
          title='SUBMIT'
          onPress={this.handleButtonPress()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The api is working as expected however the function 
    handleButtonPress()
Is being called every time I change text in my FormInput and when I click on the button I get a error of
    please attach method to this component

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
<Button
  raised
  icon={{name: 'check'}}
  title='SUBMIT'
  onPress={this.handleButtonPress()} />
```

To:

```
<Button
  raised
  icon={{name: 'check'}}
  title='SUBMIT'
  onPress={() => this.handleButtonPress()} />
```

**Edit:**

When adding `this.handleButtonPress()` to your `onPress` props, you're immediately calling it. If you want to call that function, you have to wrap it with an anonymous arrow function like so `onPress{() => this.myFunction()}` or you can just reference it like so `onPress{this.myFunction}`. Both will work.

Comment: That fixed it! Could you please explain what that did? I'll mark you as correct once the 10 min limit is up